# How to enable SSL extension for Composer?

Tags: php, paypal, openssl, composer-php

I am trying to use the PayPal PHP SDK to make an online store, however the [documentation](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php#prerequisites) tells me I need composer. When I try to install composer I get [this error](http://gyazo.com/3185b542dfe7444218b372d5c2068c86). I have no idea what this means, or how to fix it. What can I do to fix this? I

P.S. There are quite a few questions about this on SO, however, all of them that I have seen ask about using WAMP or something similar. I have no intention of using WAMP, or anything like that. The only thing I am trying to do is install composer properly.

**EDIT:** I am just using the Composer installer for Windows.

Comment: You could use [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) instead (there are many PHP environments for Windows). What environment are you trying to install under then?

Comment: @Machavity I wasn't really planning on having a test enviornment. This is a really small project and I just put it up on a dev subdomain of my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need PHP installed whether you have a full test environment running or not.  If you can't run PHP from the command line Composer stuff doesn't work.  With a basic install of PHP the openssl extension is included so that error would go away.

You can [install PHP manually](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php) on its own, or you could just install WAMP or any of the many others.  I use Zend Server myself.  It just installs everything for you so that it works without needing to mess with manual installation.

Once PHP in general is installed, though, that should get rid of this error.

Comment: Thanks! I was misunderstanding what needed to be done.

Comment: After installing PHP with that link you gave me I still got that error. I even tried uncommenting the openssl extension line in the php.ini as I have seen in other questions, it still gives me that error.

Comment: Does Composer have some sort of issue? The php_openssl.dll exists in the /ext directory, the line is not commented. Why on earth does the installed tell me it isn't there when it clearly is???

Comment: Hmmm...must be something else going on.  all I've ever done is install it with the windows msi installer and I've never had any issues.  Not sure what could be causing that, I guess.  Sorry.

Comment: I just got it to work! Apparently it doesn't like stand alone PHP. I installed WAMP and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!